# OpenGL - Nothing appearing on screen

Tags: c, opengl

I'm using Windows 7 with VC++ 2010

I'm trying to draw a simple point to a screen but it's not showing.
The screen is clearing to black so I know that I have a valid OpenGL context etc...

Basically my OpenGL code boils down to this (I don't have a depth buffer at this point):

```
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective( 45.0, 1018.0 / 743.0, 5.0, 999.0 );
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();

glColor4f( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
glPointSize( 100 );
glBegin( GL_POINTS );
glVertex2i( 0, 0 );
glEnd();

SwapBuffers( hdc );
```

The initialization code for OpenGL is this:

```
glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
glHint( GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST );
```

The problem is that nothing appears on the screen, the only thing that happens is the screen gets cleared.

Comment: If you solve your own question, it's good if you can post the solution as an answer and accept it instead of editing it into your question. This lets you get upvotes for your answer, as well as helping by marking the question as solved. Thanks.

Comment: Tom, did you actually try disabling the Depth Test while working through my checklist? Cause I wonder whether glDepthRange should have any effect when having the Depth Test disabled...

Comment: I did disable the depth test and change glDepthRange, so I guess it does. I cannot be sure though because I'm new and don't really know what I'm doing :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I had called glDepthRange misunderstanding what it actually did, I was calling it like this: `glDepthRange( nearPlane, farPlane )`. (which was 5.0f and 999.0f) When I removed this call everything was able to draw correctly. Thankyou very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 6):

Go through the following checklist (which is the [general opengl checklist from delphigl.com](http://wiki.delphigl.com/index.php/Checkliste_Allgemein) (de_DE), which we usually give people to go through when they don't see anything):

- Is your object accidentially painted in black? Try and change the `glClearColor`.
- Do you have texturing enabled accidentially? Disable it before drawing with `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`.
- Try disabling the following tests:

  - GL_DEPTH_TEST
  - GL_CULL_FACE
  - GL_ALPHA_TEST
- Check whether your `glViewport` is setup correctly.
- Try translating your Model View Matrix out of the near-clipping-plane (5.0 in your case) with `glTranslatef(0, 0, -6.0)`

---

There are several potential issues. The main problem will be how you are using the [`gluPerspective`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) projection. `gluPerspective` is for perspectivic view and as such, it won't display anything at the (0, 0, 0) in View Coordinates. In your setup, you forbid displaying anything before (0, 0, 5) in View Coordinates (near clipping plane). I suggest setting your point to `glVertex3f(0., 0., 10.)` and try again. Another solution would be to use `glTranslatef` to move your View Coordinates around by more than 5 units.

Also `glPointSize` will probably not accept your value of `100`, as common implementations are limited to a point size of 64.

For a good start with OpenGL, I'd also recommend reading up on [Nehes Tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/). They might not be State-Of-The-Art, but cover anything you're facing right now.

Comment: I tried `glTranslatef( 0, 0, 10 );` which didn't change it. Then I tried `glVertex3f( 0, 0, 10 )` which didn't change it either, I also did `glPointSize( 50 )` and still nothing is showing up on the screen. I've looked at Nehe's tutorials too which is where most of my code right now comes from.

Comment: Did you try ``glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);`` and the original point location?

Comment: That is strange then. Are you sure you did not miss anything to paste from your implementation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, here is an expanded version of my whole main loop in case I missed anything: http://pastebin.com/tQM7kWih

Comment: @TomTetlaw I added a checklist you can go through. I cannot spot what the precise problem is right now.

Comment: I went through all of those and none changed the outcome :( Maybe it's a driver issue? I recently updated my video driver?

Comment: @TomTetlaw I'm really out of ideas. Maybe someone else can help out here then.